# Trouble comparing two directories

Tags: c#

I am trying to compare two directories to see what files are in directory 1 that are not in directory 2. I have the following code:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir1 = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(pathA);
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir2 = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(pathB);

IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> list1 = dir1.GetFiles("*.PRN");
IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> list2 = dir2.GetFiles("*.PRN");

IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> list3 = list1.Except(list2);

Console.WriteLine("The following files are in list1 but not list2:");

foreach (var v in list3)
{
    Console.WriteLine(v);
}
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
Console.ReadKey();
```

When this runs, it clearly lists all the files that are in directory 1, but many of them are already in directory 2. I can see this by just looking through Windows Explorer and looking at file names. What am I missing?

EDIT:

I believe the problem is in the file compare section. I am trying to get it to ignore the case of the file extension. I have tried this:

```
    class FileCompare : System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<System.IO.FileInfo>
{
    public FileCompare() { }

    public bool Equals(System.IO.FileInfo f1, System.IO.FileInfo f2)
    {
        //return (f1.Name.ToUpper == f2.Name.ToUpper &&
        //        f1.Length == f2.Length);

        return (string.Equals(f1.Name, f2.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && f1.Length == f2.Length);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(System.IO.FileInfo fi)
    {
        string s = String.Format("{0}{1}", fi.Name, fi.Length);
        return s.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

But that is still not working. You can see I commented out another attempt to just make everything upper case in the comparison, but it wouldn't take that.

Comment: FileInfo also holds date and time info. Shouldn't you only be comparing the filename?

Comment: Are you sure there aren't minor discrepancies in the file names?

Comment: I don't think the `Equals()` method for `System.IO.FileInfo` does what you want. Why don't you define what you mean for a file to "already [be] in directory 2"? Do you mean the same file name? The exact same bytes?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for files of the exact same file name.

Comment: @roliu You are right. Neither the `FileInfo` class or any of its base classes override the `Equals` method, so this uses the reference equality inherited from the `System.Object` implementation of these `virtual` methods.

Answer (score 7):

You are going to need to use the overloaded version of `Except()` and pass it a custom implementation of `IEqualityComparer` which indicates exactly your criteria for what defines an exact match of two `FileInfo` objects.

See the example here and modify to your own needs:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There's an example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546137.aspx) that shows you how to do this.

Create your `IEqualityComparer` implementation

```
class FileCompare : System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<System.IO.FileInfo>
{
    public FileCompare() { }

    public bool Equals(System.IO.FileInfo f1, System.IO.FileInfo f2)
    {
        return (f1.Name == f2.Name &&
                f1.Length == f2.Length);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(System.IO.FileInfo fi)
    {
        string s = String.Format("{0}{1}", fi.Name, fi.Length);
        return s.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then use the `Except` overload with your comparer.

```
var queryList1Only = (from file in list1
                      select file).Except(list2, myFileCompare);
```

Comment: This is the way I tried it at first and it didn't work either. So I tried the more simple method. Both still return files that exist in both directories and I only want to see those that are in directory 1.

Comment: @RobertWiglesworth This solution will just fine, you'll simply need to do a case insensitive comparison in your comparer.
`String.Compare(f1.Name,f2.Name,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0`

Comment: @LeeHiles If you want that, use `String.Equals(f1.Name, f2.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`.

Comment: Hey guys, I have tried it both ways that you mentioned. Currently my file comparer looks like this:
return (string.Equals(f1.Name, f2.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && f1.Length == f2.Length);
and it still isn't working.

Comment: @RobertWiglesworth - Try removing the `f1.Length == f2.Length` check and see if that works. This means that the files aren't the same (as they're different sizes) but the names are.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are only interested in the *names*, project your sequences to sequences of names with `.Select` extension method of LINQ:

```
IEnumerable<string> list1 = dir1.GetFiles("*.PRN").Select(fi => fi.Name);
IEnumerable<string> list2 = dir2.GetFiles("*.PRN").Select(fi => fi.Name);
IEnumerable<string> list3 = list1.Except(list2);
```

(You could use `var`, implicit typing.)

This works becase the default equality comparer for `string` does an ordinal and case-sensitive comparison (not just reference equality comparison like the `FileInfo` class comes with).

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ

```
        var list3 = from c in list1
                    where !(from o in list2
                            select o.Name)
                           .Contains(c.Name)
                    select c;
```

There might also be a problem of different cases

You could try

```
.Equals(c.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Instead of

```
.Contains(c.Name)
```

Or convert everything into lower case before comparing.

Comment: This still showed all the files in list 1 even though they exist in list 2.

Comment: That is strange... are you sure the name are exactly the same? (same case, not extra space)

Comment: OK, here's something odd... I tried using Intersect instead to see if it listed any there were the same. I got one value. It was for a file that I manually copied from dir 1 to dir 2 just to make sure I had the correct folder permissions. I checked the properties on them and dir 1 shows them as file type .prn and dir 2 shows them as file type .PRN. Is that a system preference or something?

Comment: OK, so what this appears to have come down to is that one directory has the extensions in lower case and the other directory has the extensions in upper case. I didn't realize this when looking via Windows Explorer because it does not show file extensions. Is there any way to tell it to ignore the case of the extension? or even ignore the extension altogether?

Comment: @Robert I updated the response. You could also look at the System.IO.Path class.